# Argument notation in Python documentation

Tags: python

I read the Python documentation a lot and sometimes I am baffled by this notation:

> os.path.join(**path1[, path2[, ...]]**)

I somehow make that **[, path[,...]]** is a list but I would like to know if I am reading it correctly.

Bear with me, this is coming from a Java developer who is trying out Python. X)

Comment: If you ever encountered BNF notation, you remember that it puts optional parts into [square brackets].

Comment: What does BNF use for literal square brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is for multiple arguments. You could call that method with 1 or more variables. That particular method could be called with:

1. `join(path1)`
2. `join(path1, path2)`
3. `join(path1, path2, <optional parameters>)`

Option 3 can only be used when the `path2` argument is present. If you have have use C, think `printf("Number %d", number);`

According to the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), those optional parameters are for more paths. So you could call `join(path1, path2, path3, path4)` or with as many paths as you like.

Comment: It should be "with one or more". +1 for all else.

Comment: But can the parameters be passed, say, in one list?

Comment: @Jeune: I don't think so, but I'm not a python expert by any strech.

Comment: @Jeune: you can use *args, to unpack a list as arguments to a function. ie os.path(*[arg1, arg2, arg3]), or if args was already a list.

Answer (score 7):

The brackets indicate an optional parameter. The ellipses indicate a variable-length argument list.